# Flutter BoxShadow как сделать внутреннюю тень у контейнера?

Tags: flutter, figma, box-shadow

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: kIconColor,
              shape: BoxShape.circle
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: kBlacColor.withOpacity(0.35),
                  blurRadius: 4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Этот код работает для внешней тени:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же необходимо получить следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть еще один вариант, но у меня он не работает. Экспортировать из figma уже готовую кнопку в svg формате, но тут появляется проблема... Flutter почему-то не видит тень. Помогите кто чем может пожалуйста! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можешь попробовать вот так

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class InnerShadow extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const InnerShadow({
    Key key,
    this.blur = 10,
    this.color = Colors.black38,
    this.offset = const Offset(10, 10),
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final double blur;
  final Color color;
  final Offset offset;

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    final _RenderInnerShadow renderObject = _RenderInnerShadow();
    updateRenderObject(context, renderObject);
    return renderObject;
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, _RenderInnerShadow renderObject) {
    renderObject
      ..color = color
      ..blur = blur
      ..dx = offset.dx
      ..dy = offset.dy;
  }
}

class _RenderInnerShadow extends RenderProxyBox {
  double blur;
  Color color;
  double dx;
  double dy;

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child == null) return;

    final Rect rectOuter = offset & size;
    final Rect rectInner = Rect.fromLTWH(
      offset.dx,
      offset.dy,
      size.width - dx,
      size.height - dy,
    );
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas..saveLayer(rectOuter, Paint());
    context.paintChild(child, offset);
    final Paint shadowPaint = Paint()
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcATop
      ..imageFilter = ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blur, sigmaY: blur)
      ..colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.srcOut);

    canvas
      ..saveLayer(rectOuter, shadowPaint)
      ..saveLayer(rectInner, Paint())
      ..translate(dx, dy);
    context.paintChild(child, offset);
    context.canvas..restore()..restore()..restore();
  }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
InnerShadow(
  blur: 5,
  color: const Color(0xFF477C70),
  offset: const Offset(5, 5),
  child: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      color: Color(0xFFE9EFEC),
    ),
    height: 100,
  ),
)
```